# Indices share row data in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working with a numpy array that is fairly dense (like 20-50%), but has large regions that are the same value. For example I might have an array something like:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [1 2 3 4]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [3 4 5 6]]
```

Instead of storing the rows filled with the same values (the 0 row) as separate rows in memory, is there a way to share the row memory so that rows 0 and 2 both access the same memory? I'm looking for something that's either built into numpy or will allow normal numpy functions to work with such an array. I need it to seem like I'm still using a numpy array.

A few notes:

I know I can just create an object in python that just maps the input indices to their data index in some numpy array, but I also want this object to be treated like a numpy array, so I can call numpy functions on it.

I've seen sparse matrices before, but my data is not really that sparse, so it seems to me that the sparse matrix algorithms won't work as efficiently.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking is possible or it is worth, but maybe someone will surprise us

Comment: could it be you are looking for this? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: If the whole array has a pattern of duplicates, it's possible to use some striding tricks to avoid 'copies'.  But where the pattern is irregular, no. The data for the array is stored in a flat (1d) buffer.  It's the striding and shape that makes it multidimensional.

Comment: @timgeb I mentioned above I don't want sparse matricies. My data is not actually that sparse. For example, with the CSR matrix, each nonzero value (I think) is represented by 3 numbers. This would mean for a matrix that 50% full it would use more memory than the dense version.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You could kind of handle some NumPy functions with a class that implements [`__array_ufunc__`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#numpy.class.__array_ufunc__), but it'd only handle ufuncs. You'd have to implement indexing yourself, and for most of the rest of NumPy, you'd be stuck with options that implicitly convert your object to a real, dense array, at best.

`scipy.sparse` sparse matrices come closest to a built-in option, but even then, sparse matrices are incompatible with most NumPy functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save memory, maybe playing with dtype might help. I have no idea, is it faster or slower...

```
from sys import getsizeof
>>> arr2 = np.ones((1000,1000))
>>> getsizeof(arr2)
8000112
>>> arr2 = np.ones((1000,1000),dtype='>i2')
>>> getsizeof(arr2)
2000112
```

But if you want to calculate with floats, you could try also dtype='single', in case high accuracy is not needed.